# Direct sum in Eq.(25) of *A Grand Unification of Quantum Algorithms* should be changed into $\sum_\lambda$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I have a problem when I read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02859), is there someone who has occasionally read this paper and can help me solve the problem?

The problem is just about the notation used in the paper, the authors stated that $U=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\mathcal{H} & \sqrt{I-\mathcal{H}^{2}} \\ \sqrt{I-\mathcal{H}^{2}} & -\mathcal{H}\end{array}\right]$, where $\mathcal{H}=\sum_{\lambda} \lambda|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|$. But later, they stated again in eq.(25):
$$
\begin{aligned}
U &=\bigoplus_{\lambda}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & \sqrt{1-\lambda^{2}} \\
\sqrt{1-\lambda^{2}} & -\lambda
\end{array}\right] \otimes|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda| \\
&=\bigoplus_{\lambda}\left[\sqrt{1-\lambda^{2}} X+\lambda Z\right] \otimes|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda| \\
&=: \bigoplus_{\lambda} R(\lambda) \otimes|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|,
\end{aligned}
$$
My question is, should the direct sum be changed into $\sum_\lambda$? Because the dimension in the direct sum form seems not the same as the original $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems that two possible notations, either
$$
\sum_\lambda R(\lambda)\otimes |\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|
$$
or
$$
\bigoplus_\lambda R(\lambda)
$$
have been merged (the second needs to be interpreted as 'in the basis $\{|\lambda\rangle\}$'). As you say, I think you're better off with the normal sum.

Comment: Em.. Maybe you miss something? I found that I wrote $\bigoplus_\lambda R\left( \lambda \right)\otimes |\lambda \rangle \langle \lambda |$ instead of $\bigoplus_\lambda R\left( \lambda \right) $ ..

Comment: Maybe I think it's more tend to show the essence of what they want to convey instead of mathematically equivalence?